# Modifiying j2me midlet

Tags: java-me, midp

I want to change some strings in opensource app ( testing purpose ). So I decompiled my app using jad decompiler.

Original class file http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32657135/YourTube.class

issued command `Jad.exe Yourtube.jar.java`

Got jad as output http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32657135/YourTube.jad.java

**Compiling Code Again with no modification**

command in cmd `javac Yourtube.jar.java`

**Error**

```
YourTube.jad.java:57: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR monitorenter ;
                 ^
YourTube.jad.java:57: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR monitorenter ;
                  ^
YourTube.jad.java:59: error: not a statement
        this;
        ^
YourTube.jad.java:66: error: ';' expected
        JVM INSTR monitorenter ;
                 ^
YourTube.jad.java:66: error: not a statement
        JVM INSTR monitorenter ;
                  ^
YourTube.jad.java:68: error: not a statement
        this;
        ^
6 errors
```

I want to know, why I am getting this error on recompiling. Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: "jad decompiler" what is this?

Comment: jad is a java decompiler

Comment: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) doesn't state that this tool supports decompilation of **[preverified class files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19592-01/817-2343/chap3.html#compilation%20and%20preverification "what's this?")** like ones in midlet, did you check its documentation?

Comment: so what can be used in its place?

Comment: apparently, a decompiler that supports classes like in midlet (JDK 1.3 version 47.0, preverified), what else?