# Converting .java to .class

Tags: java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modifiying j2me midlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538550/modifiying-j2me-midlet)

I am trying to convert this file to .class

But getting lots of error.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32657135/YourTube.jad.java

It is for j2me platoform

Command used 
javac YourTube.jad.java

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permission to be using this code?

The errors seem to be coming from issues caused be a faulty decompiler- and unless you have a very specific reason to be running around with a Java decompiler, I'd have to guess that you don't have permission to access this code to begin with.

Comment: Here is orginal source code, same errors with it. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32657135/YourTube.java

Comment: Yeah , we can compile it without modifying. Its stated in this apps license term.

Comment: The second file creates some very different errors from the looks of it. What's the first error message you can see when you're trying to compile it?